# unable to run the react-native-background-task. error while inserting code to MainApplication.java

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, npm, background-task

One manual step is still needed - in your project file android/app/src/main/java/myapp/MainApplication.java, add the following to the end of the onCreate() method:
            **BackgroundTaskPackage.useContext(this);**

Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warning 
23 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 21 up-to-date
G:\background\android\app\src\main\java\com\background\MainApplication.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
G:\background\android\app\src\main\java\com\background\MainApplication.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    BackgroundTaskPackage.useContext();

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in React Native 0.61 by manually linking the module (and disabling auto-linking for the package: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)